# Letter "i" autocorrection windows 10

Tags: windows, ms-office, autocorrect

I am trying to switch auto-correct of letter "i" to a capital "I". I would like to leave it lowercase if I type it lowercase.
I am pretty sure it is windows 10 settings, as it does the auto-correct in outlook, office and anywhere else. I have switched off auto-correct but still does not work.
I have tried every possible setting in office>options>proofing>, I have added an exemption for "i" but also did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it. Office>options>proofing>autocorrect options> and then delete a rule for replacing "i" with "I".